# How to force data labels to all be displayed?

Tags: highcharts

I use a bubble chart to present data and some of the data lables are hidden in the chart, while others are visible:

[image]

The blue bubble with no visible label does have one (as all the others) and it appears when some series are excluded. So this is really a display preference (and not a missing label).

The labels visibility is configured via

```
   plotOptions: {
        bubble: {
            minSize: 30
        },
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.service}'

            },
            animation: false
        }
    },
```

**Is there a parameter which can force the visibility?** (even if it may impair the readability which is, I guess, the reason for highcharts to hide some labels).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `allowOverlap` option as true.

> allowOverlap: Boolean
>
> Whether to allow data labels to overlap. To make the labels less
>   sensitive for overlapping, the dataLabels.padding can be set to 0.
>   Defaults to false.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.allowOverlap